# Adjoints of similar operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Does this equality hold: $(UAU^{-1})^* = UA^*U^{-1}$? where $U$ is invertible. Suppose these operators are defined on a Banach space.

Answer (score 1):

In general $(UAU^{-1})^* = UA^*U^{-1}$ is not correct.

Correct is: $(UAU^{-1})^* =(U^*)^{-1}A^*U^*$